# AnyLogic release agents from queue within another proess block

Tags: process, queue, anylogic

In my process, I want that the agents waiting in the queue to be released, when the agent before has completed its process.
Is there a simple way to activate the longest in the queue waiting agent, when a agent has entered the moveTo4 block?
The agents may not move until they are released.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to put a `Hold` block between the `queue` and `moveTo2` blocks.

Set it up so it is initially unblocked and it is blocked "Manual (use block(), unblock() methods)".

In the `moveTo4` block's "on at exit" code block, call `myHoldBlock.unblock()`. This will open the "flood gates" and all agents from `queue` will spill downstream (if possible).

You may want to also call `myHoldBlock.block()` when an agent enters `moveTo4`, you will want to experiment a bit. Check the [help](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/hold.html#hold) on the Hold block, it is really powerful.